# Why doesn't NSDateFormatter return a NSString?

Tags: objective-c

Why does this message not return a string:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formattedDate = (@"Date for today %@:", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expression does return an NSString, but without formatting. To format an NSString properly, you use the [`+stringWithFormat:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_):

```
NSString* formattedDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date for today %@:",
                           [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
```

---

The expression `a, b` is a "[comma expression](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/co.htm)". It will evaluate `a` and `b` in sequence, and return the value of `b`. In you case, it will return the string of date only.

Most of the case, you do not want to use a comma expression.

---

Also, the `dateFormatter` needs to be configured before using. For instance,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
...
... [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today] ...
...
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: I have just tried that, it returns "Date for today:" without the actual date though?

Comment: @The: You need to call `-setTimeStyle:` and `-setDateStyle:` for the dateFormatter before using it.